# Ajax request is not function error in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to show my validation errors using ajax request returned by validator, but console keep returning this error. Is it because of my jQuery version (3.4.1)?

JS console output

```
TypeError: $.ajax(...).done(...).error is not a function
```

Ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Validation for all field
    $(".guest-query-submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action

        //Define inputs
        let _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
        let title = $("input[name='title']").val();
        let description = $("input[name='description']").val();
        let category = $("input[name='category']").val();
        let attachment = $("input[name='attachment']").val();
        let county = $("input[name='county']").val();
        let startDate = $("input[name='startDate']").val();
        let endDate = $("input[name='endDate']").val();
        let flexibility = $("input[name='flexibility']").val();
        let contactName = $("input[name='contactName']").val();
        let contactEmail = $("input[name='contactEmail']").val();
        let contactNumber = $("input[name='contactNumber']").val();

        //Starting ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('send-guest-query')}}",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                _token:_token,
                title:title,
                description:description,
                category:category,
                attachment:attachment,
                county:county,
                startDate:startDate,
                endDate:endDate,
                flexibility:flexibility,
                contactName:contactName,
                contactEmail:contactEmail,
                contactNumber:contactNumber },
            dataType: "json"
        }).done (function (data) {
            if(data.status === 200) {
                Swal.fire({ //SweetAlert
                    title: 'Success',
                    text: 'Your query was sent successfully!',
                    type: 'success',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Continue'
                })
            }}).error(function (data) {
            if (data.status === 422 && data.responseJSON) {
                console.log(data);
                if (Object.keys(data.responseJSON.errors).length) {
                    for (field in data.responseJSON.errors) {
                        let error = data.responseJSON.errors[field];
                        let input = '#Modal input[name=' + field + ']';
                        $(input).addClass('is-invalid');
                        $(input).next('span').find('strong').text(error[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        })
     });
```

Validation part in Laravel

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'title' => 'required|string',
//            'description' => 'required|string',
//            'category' => 'required',
//            'county' => 'required',
            'startDate' => 'required',
            'endDate' => 'required',
//            'flexibility' => 'required',
            'contactName' => 'required',
            'contactEmail' => 'required',
            'contactNumber' => 'required|integer',
        ]);
        if ($validator->passes()) {
            return response()->json(['success'=>'Query successfully sent!'],200);
        }
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()],422);
```

Also while at this topic. Is this even recommended by today's standard to solve validation  like this when using modal. I know using Vue would probably make my live easier here but i don't want to touch Vue until i have basic knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: It's `.fail()` not `.error()`.

Comment: Tried with `.fail()` same error. I forgot it to change it back before i posted my thread.

Comment: The error will not be the same. Can you please post what you get when trying `fail()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you were right, error is not same. Now i'm getting 
 `TypeError: can't convert undefined to object`

Comment: If you double click that error in the console it will take you to the line which caused it, and you can determine from there exactly what value is undefined.

Comment: Yep, found the issue. Thanks for the tip. Line below caused error.

`if (Object.keys(data.responseJSON.errors).length)`

Now i have to figure out how to get error messages from json below inputs.

Answer (score 0):

well I dont know if this will help but usually this is the way I use ajax requests I find it much easier I hope this helps

```js
   $.ajax({
            contentType: *the type your sending ex:'application/json'*,
            url: *Your url*,
            type: *POST or GET*,
            data: *Your Data ex: JSON.stringify(model) since i am sending json*,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Changed my code to this: https://pastebin.com/p54EFLk5 unfortunately nothing is returned to console after that. :/

Comment: please enter the console.error(err) before the if statement likewise:
    `error: function (data) { 
console.error(data);
 if (data.status === 422 && data.responseJSON) {..`
you would do that just to check if it is entering your error statement also so when it is printed in the log it shows error in red

Comment: Read the comments under the question. The $.ajax setup was not the issue